# titanium android configuration OSX

Tags: android, configuration, appcelerator-mobile

I am new at this, and I am following the tut from "Appcelerator Titanium Smartphone App Development Cookbook"

Now I have built pretty much the all app, but when I try to build in android I get a very awkward result. see pics:

[image]
[image]
[image]

what should i change in the config to display properly? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing to change in configuration. 
You need to provide different resources for different device resolutions (as retina and non-retina pics for iPhone there are also different resolutions and sizes for android). Take a look at [User Interface Fundamentals](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/User_Interface_Fundamentals) of Titanium docs.Additionally you should use always 'dp' (device-independent pixel) for all sizes (height, width, top, left, etc.). Then Titanium recalculates this sizes for the current device.

```
Ti.UI.createView({
  height: '20 dp',
  width: '20 dp',
  left: '20 dp'
};
```

Comment: mr.VVoo thanks for the pointer, guess more reading is needed. btw could you give me a very short sample code on how to use dp, please?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in your tiApp.xml file

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <manifest>
   <supports-screens android:anyDensity="false"/>
  </manifest>
 </android>
```

This will basically scales them according to the android devices in use, since android devices are coming in different resolutions. Please refer [Defaults For Android Layouts](http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2011/06/new-defaults-for-android-layouts-in-1-7.html). I used it and found it working with different resolution even for tablets also